# Do I Need to Buy Full SD Specification

Tags: sd

I'm designing a system with an ARMv7 processor. My host processor support SDIO protocol and I wish to use this unit to connect the host to a Memory card and a WiFi module that both are compliant with *SDIO Card Specification Version 2.0*

My question is, What is the difference between simplified and full version of *SD Memory Card Specification* and does simplified version adequate for the above case or I need to buy full SD Specification somewhere down the road.

**Note:** We are not going to sell this product so I don't have any concern about the legal issues.

Comment: Look in the docs of the parts you use, they often contain licenses to use that stuff and the fees are part of the price of that part.

Comment: You should concern just on the adopted file system. If using standard FAT, there is no problem, but enhanced versions are not free.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, Thanks for your comment. Please note that I'm not asking about if I require licence from SD Assosiation or not but I'm asking if the simplified version of SD Specification is adequate for me in the design process?. Here is what I found in my parts datasheet. "The SD/SDIO controller is compatible with the standard SD Host Controller Specification Version 2.0 Part A2". which is refered to the document I don't have access to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to design my own SD-card controller (SD/SDHC/SDXC) within FPGA reading some vendor specifications and documents freely available from the SD association. I think you will need to buy full spec if you want to manufacture SD-cards.